# How to Calculate Area Under the Curve in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire, integral

Can someone assist me in calculate the area under the curve in Spotfire w/o using R or S+?

I am looking to rank the data in [K] (1 = largest value) for each Well, and then calculate the cumulative sums of [P] (ranked by descending K) and [K], then calculate and plot (as curves) the % cumulative sum of [P] and [K], calculate the area under each curve, for each Well (what is the expression).

I would like to calculate each column in Spotfire, but my main problems are  ranking [K] so there are no ties (I was attempting to Rank first by [K] and then by [Depth]), summing the values of [P] and [K] by ranked [K] for each Well, and then calculating the Riemann Sums (Area) under each curve.

[image: Data_Table_and_Curves]

Comment: My thought process to calculated the area under the curve was to: Calculated Reimann sums calculated column --> sum all the Reimann Sums. I think I am getting the syntax wrong because I am getting numbers that are off compared to my excel sheet where I know how to do this. My errors are due to trying to calculate for each well (A and B)

Comment: It's not just some details,  but completely new requirements:(. I'd copy this question to a new one, keeping reference to this original question, than would revert changes to go back to the original question.

Comment: @Máté, I just added a new questions. I appreciate the help with questions and protocol for posting (still new)! Sorry for the slow learning ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to add a new column (`[period]`) to calculate a unique time, otherwise Spotfire would get confused of different times in the datasets:
`[well] & Log10([time] + 1)`

Then add a cross table, drag `[well]` to the vertical axis, and enter this expression to cell values: 
`Sum(([pressure] + Avg([pressure]) over (Next([period]))) / 2 * (Avg([time]) over (Next([period])) - [time]))`

Alternatively you can add a new column (`[AUDPC_helper]`) too see step by step calculations:
`([pressure] + Avg([pressure]) over (Intersect(NextPeriod([period]),[well]))) / 2 * (Avg([time]) over (Intersect(NextPeriod([period]),[well])) - [time])`
Just need to get summary of this column in e.g. a cross table

[image]

Comment: Thanks Máté! I will test this out and let you know

Comment: Máté,
I am a little confused with how you are coming up with the [period] property. I understand it is supposed to be a unique identifier, but will it not scale my data erroneously?
Also, is your formula (AUDPC_helper) for Riemann Sums?

Comment: It won't scale your data, just creates an identifier combining [well] and [time] to be able to sort them independently and also in an ordered way. Just insert the column, then create a new raw table visualization to see how it works.

Comment: Máté just did it (sorry it was my first question so I didn't realize)

Comment: Máté, I just ran into another snag on a variation of the same problem (calculating area under the curve). Should I ask here or as a new question?

Comment: @flgeo if it's variation of the problem, then please update your question with it.

Comment: I have updated the question - as you'll see I ran into a couple new snags.

Comment: when I use all my data and calculate [period] I am not always getting a unique item, ie., sometimes I get duplicates because I have multiple occurrences of the same time. Is there anyway to customize this?